# i click the "process to checkout " button in the cart , it running for a long time to jump the checkout page

Tags: checkout-page

After i added the product, then i click the "process to checkout " button in the cart , it running for a long time that can jump to the checkout one-page,i think this question will be make customer wait a long time ,and a large percent maybe make them give up the order.

[image]

Comment: please debug the code which is exeuted after click on button.

Comment: HI, Dhiren: maybe i'm not sure know how to found the reason, can you help me to check it ! Thank you very much! This is my site :   supwatch.com